# How to detect whether the supporter is logged in using php

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am looking to make an online chat support.....Anyone can chat with the supporter through a chat window without login.....I need an indication showing the suporter is online or offline....

**When the supporter is ONLINE the window must shows like**

[image]

**And when the supporter is OFFLINE the window must shows like**

[image]

How can i do this..????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your supporters need to send heartbeats to the server, indicating that they are still "alive". If they close their window, they will stop emitting heartbeats, and they will be considered "offline".

All you need to have is a table with the last heartbeat from every supporter. All supporters should be considered "online" until 2x the time of a heartbeat is set.

For example, you define a heartbeat should be sent every 15 seconds. If, aftter 30 seconds, no heartbeat has been sent, the supporter is offline.

You can send heartbeats with jQuery's [Ajax functions](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

Create one table which contains the supporter login and logout details with occupied or not by other.

When anyone will request for an supporter, check the entry into the same table.

if any supporter will be there ... do the same whatever you wish...

Comment: Thanks for the support...But the pblm is when the supporter closes his window without clicking the logout link....how can i detect that....????

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve that by adding an extra column in your database. Whenever someone logs on the value will be set to 1,  if he logs out set it to 0. Then you can check which user is logged in.

Comment: Thanks for the support...But the pblm is when the supporter closes his window without clicking the logout link....how can i detect that....????

Comment: You cant Do that with only php, you probably need to use a Javascript, Check out this link http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/insights/825556-using-onbeforeunload-javascript-event